# Computing a sequence by recurrence

Tags: summation, core-language, difference-equations

I am trying to create a list where each element of the list is calculated using the sum of all previous elements of the list and also uses the $N$th element of another list. The initial value of the list is a known quantity. $k1$ is simply a constant value. $k2$ is a known list of $N$ elements.

$\quad \quad Q_N=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}{k1(Q_i/k2_N)},\,N>0$
$\quad \quad Q_0=k0$

I'm not quite sure how to code this. I think the `Nest` function is somewhat close to what I want, but I need to keep plugging in the sum of all previous values, not just the previous value.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: As I keep digging, `FoldList` seems like it might be useful, but I just can't seem to crack this problem.

Edit 2: It may be relevant that $N$ is going to be rather large. The context is a numeric solution to the time evolution of a system. So I want to have smaller time-steps, which leads to a large number of elements.

Comment: Try something like `Accumulate`? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Accumulate.html

Comment: Accumulate looks interesting. I'll read up on that. Thanks!

Comment: Ultimately, do you only need `Q[N]` or all `Q[i]` for `0 ≤ i ≤ N`?

Comment: Ultimately, I will need all Q[i]'s, but just getting Q[N] would be a great start.

Comment: Is k1 an arbitrary function? If yes, then `FoldList` which seemed to be the way to do it no longer works.

Comment: k1 is a constant. k2's are also constants, but there are N of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q[0] = 1;
k2 = {1,2,3,4,5};
q[n_] := q[n] = Sum[k1 q[i]/k2[[n]], {i, 0, n - 1}]

q /@ Range@5
(*{5, 15, 35, 70, 126}*)
```

Comment: You should note that this is still $O(n)$.  It's nice and simple though.

Comment: Wow, this is very slick. This was actually one of my first thoughts. There is a tutorial in the documentation called **Functions That Remember Values They Have Found**. I couldn't initially wrap my brain around it, but now I see how simple it is. I'm assuming that your value of k1 is 5. I would appreciate if you could confirm that, as I am making sure I understand this fully. Also, I posted another question that has to do with this situation. This would be a good answer to that if you want to put it up there too. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71432/

Comment: Ummm. Scratch my above comment. I meant to say, this is $O(n^2)$, not $O(n)$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do it using `FoldList`. It will give you a list of all $Q_i$ for $0 < i \le n$.

```
n = 5;
k0 = 1;
k1 = 5;
k2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
FoldList[
 (k2[[#2]] + k1)#/k2[[#2 + 1]] &,
 k0 k1/k2[[1]], 
 Range[n - 1]
]
(* {5, 15, 35, 70, 126} *)
```

An important observation, which reduces the runtime from $O(n^2)$ to $O(n)$: for $i > 1$ we have

$$ Q_N = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{k_1 Q_i}{k_{2,N}} = \sum_{i=0}^{N-2} \frac{k_1 Q_i}{k_{2,N}} + \frac{k_1 Q_{N-1}}{k_{2,N}} = \frac{k_{2,N-1}}{k_{2,N}}\sum_{i=0}^{N-2} \frac{k_1 Q_i}{k_{2,N-1}} + \frac{k_1 Q_{N-1}}{k_{2,N}} = \frac{Q_{N-1}}{k_{2,N}}(k_{2,N-1}+k_1) $$

Note that this doesn't hold for $Q_1$, which is why we start the folding from there, instead of $Q_0$, such the first call of the function computes $Q_2$.

This observation lets us compute $Q_N$ solely based on $Q_{N-1}$, instead of having to look at all previous $Q_i$. The function inside the `FoldList` computes exactly this expression, where `#` is $Q_{N-1}$ and `#2` is $N$.

Lastly, we fold onto a range of $i$ values, which we need to index into the $k_2$ list.

Comment: When I try to run your code, I get an error that has to do with the #k2 part. It says Part 2 (and 3 and 4) of #k2 does not exist. I simply copied and pasted your code into a newly started kernel, so that there wouldn't be any errors from stuff I had tried. I am running Mathematica 10.0.

Comment: @matt Sorry, I accidentally swapped two characters.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still working on understanding what is going on, but your example is working on my machine with that last edit.

Comment: @matt If it helps, think of `#` as $Q_{N-1}$ and of `#2` as $N$.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFirstList = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {10}];

mySecondList = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[], {10}];

Take[FoldList[Plus, 0, myFirstList], {2,Length[myFirstList] + 1}] + mySecondList
```

Comment: You've got an error: `myFistList` and correcting it produces another error.

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell; were you aiming for `Accumulate[myFirstList] + mySecondList`?